# Blazor hot reload for scss files (.net 6.0)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I currently have a blazor wasm application running on .net 6.0 with VS2022.
From my understanding hot reload was available for css files, unfortunately, my application use .scss files instead of .css and the hot reload does not seems to work.

I'm currently using hot reload via CLI and the command dotnet watch, when I make a change in the file, the watcher seems to understand that there is an update but the change does not show up until I hit ctrl+R to rebuild the entire application.

Here is the message I receive from dotnet watch when a change is done in the scss file :  **File changed: C:\Users\Mark\source\repos\Test\Client\scss\test.scss.
watch : Hot reload of changes succeeded.**

Any ideas on how to enable hot reload for scss or if it's even possible?

PS: I'm using the library LibSassBuilder

Comment: I have tested Hot Reload extensively on a stock standard Blazor wasm project using .net 6.0.100. It does NOT work on Edit or Save despite the videos etc. Hot Reload on Save is checked. I have tested in VSCode and VS2022 with standard css. Both IDEs have the latest updates. I have also tested with Tailwindcss which needs pre processing and it definately does not work with that either so I am guessing it wont work with scss. I also tried modification to launchSettings - also did not work.